# How to download recorded video on Sony video camera with Sony Camera API

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api, sony-lifelog-api

I am working on a project which needs to record and download a video using Sony Video Camera. I only see transfer image from the API but there is no transfer for videos. Is there any way to download the video file from the camera via wifi?

My requirement is I want live streaming data after I starts Movie recording. And after click of Capture button it should save last 10 seconds recording in my iPhone gallery. Can I get live recorded streaming data while recording is On? Also How I will fetch movie data from streamed data packets as Sample example shows only Image data fetching.

Comment: After you switch the camera function from "Remote Shooting" to "Contents Transfer" using "setCameraFunction" you should be able to run the "getContentList" function which should return a uri to the video. From here you should be able to download the video using regular HTTP GET commands.

Comment: @Robert-Sony I am getting Transport error in response of "getContentList". My requirement is I want live streaming data after I starts Movie recording. And after click of Capture button it should save last 10 seconds recording in my iPhone gallery. May I get your skype id or any id from which we can communicate? My skype id is Somnath.Rasal

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you are asking. You also don't say what camera you have.

The Liveview images continue during pause and recording. These are lower resolution/fps jpeg images, you could stack a number of these to create a 'movie'.

Your camera may also support Remote-playback, when a previously record movie is viewed in the same manner as the Liveview (ie. jpeg). You could detect the stopping of on-camera recording and then 'replay' the first 10s or so.